# Trigonometric identity not simplifying

Tags: trigonometry, proof

I have a pair of numbers {x,y} (Reals or Integers) for which I want to confirm symbolically that

```
ArcTan[y/x]+ArcTan[x/y]==Pi/2
```

Here is my attempt:

```
ClearAll[y, x];
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals && 
     x >= 0 && y >= 0, 
    FullSimplify[ArcTan[y/x] + ArcTan[x/y]]]
```

Sadly, this isn't working.  I can (sort of) prove this by generating some random pairs and confirming that this identity is true by doing this:

```
Counts[
    ArcTan[#[[1]]/#[[2]]] + ArcTan[#[[2]]/#[[1]]] == Pi/2 & /@ Partition[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 1000], 2]
]
```

This produces:

```
(* <|True -> 500|> *)
```

as I expect.  What am I missing in being able to have Mathematica symbolically prove this relationship?

Comment: **Tan[ArcTan[y/x] + ArcTan[x/y] - Pi/2] // TrigExpand**

Comment: Thank you!  Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try an equivalence like

```
TrigExpand[Tan[ArcTan[y/x] + ArcTan[x/y] - Pi/2]] == 0
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I did find that Simplify also works in place of TrigExpand.